# bloquear acesso a um determinado diretório via htaccess com senha

Tags: htaccess, apache, segurança, log

Atualmente tenho um servidor onde deixo os meus projetos web rodando, alguns deles em Laravel, até aqui sem problemas, porem eu quero criar uma restrição com senha em `.htaccess` para a raiz,

**Por exemplo:**

Tenho os domínios `site_a.dominio.com.br`, `site_b.dominio.com.br` e `dominio.com.br`, onde `site_a` e `site_b` são virtual hosts do apache e o `dominio.com.br` retornar a raiz `www`.

Tanto o `site_a` quanto o `site_b` não é necessária a senha para carregamento da pagina,  porem na raiz `dominio.com.br`, ao abrir seja solicitado a senha pelo navegador, e se possível a definição de usuário e senha no próprio `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após um pouco de busca, acabei achando a solução para meu problema, então vim compartilhar com a comunidade, (que ficou ainda melhor do que eu previa)

**.htaccess:**

```
# bloquando leitura do .hacess
<files ~ "^.*\.([Hh][Tt][Aa])">
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
    satisfy all
</files>

# Solicitando apenas Quando for a raiz do dominio
<If "req('Host') == 'dominio.com.br'">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Password Protected Area"
    AuthUserFile /home/bull/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
</If>
<Else>
    Require all granted
</Else>
```

Por questão de segurança foi adicionado o bloqueio da leitura do próprio arquivo `.htaccess`,

A lógica aplicada para a requisição da senha é, caso a URL requisitada seja por exemplo: `dominio.com.br`, ele irá solicitar a senha caso não, (em suma os subdomínios ou acesso local pelo ip interno do servidor) ele irá abri carregar as paginas sem a necessidade da senha.

**Referencias:**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359472/use-http-auth-only-if-accessing-a-specific-domain?answertab=oldest#tab-top

https://www.codigofonte.com.br/artigos/confira-20-dicas-e-truques-extremamente-uteis-do-htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Acho que o que você deseja é uma maneira para não indexar a página inicial do domínio, você pode colocar um "index.php" para autenticar e criar no mesmo um algoritmo para listar as pastar na web.

> Segue um script que preparei para você

```
<?php
$realm = 'Área restrita';

//usuário => senha
$users = array('admin' => 'senha', 'visitante' => 'senha');


function authNow() {
    global $realm;
    header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized');
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="'.$realm.'",qop="auth",nonce="'.uniqid().'",opaque="'.md5($realm).'"');
    die('Não foi possível validar seus dados');
}

if (empty($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_DIGEST'])) {
    authNow();
}


// analisar a variável PHP_AUTH_DIGEST
if (!($data = http_digest_parse($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_DIGEST'])) ||
    !isset($users[$data['username']])) {
    authNow();
}


// gerar a resposta válida
$A1 = md5($data['username'] . ':' . $realm . ':' . $users[$data['username']]);
$A2 = md5($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'].':'.$data['uri']);
$valid_response = md5($A1.':'.$data['nonce'].':'.$data['nc'].':'.$data['cnonce'].':'.$data['qop'].':'.$A2);

if ($data['response'] != $valid_response) {
    authNow();
}


// listando diretórios
$dirs = array_filter(glob('*'), 'is_dir');
echo '<h1>Início em /</h1><hr/>';
echo '<ul>';
foreach($dirs as $dir) {
    echo '<li><a href="'.$dir.'">' . $dir . '</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul><hr/>Página gerada em ' . date('d/m/Y H:i:s');


// função para decompor o http auth header
function http_digest_parse($txt)
{
    // proteção contra dados incompletos
    $needed_parts = array('nonce'=>1, 'nc'=>1, 'cnonce'=>1, 'qop'=>1, 'username'=>1, 'uri'=>1, 'response'=>1);
    $data = array();
    $keys = implode('|', array_keys($needed_parts));

    preg_match_all('@(' . $keys . ')=(?:([\'"])([^\2]+?)\2|([^\s,]+))@', $txt, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

    foreach ($matches as $m) {
        $data[$m[1]] = $m[3] ? $m[3] : $m[4];
        unset($needed_parts[$m[1]]);
    }

    return $needed_parts ? false : $data;
}
```

Comment: Rapais obrigado pela ajuda, mas sim é possível sim, com uso de password do linux eu até consigo fazer porem em uma das empresas meu chefe fazia assim e se torna pratico pra coisas simples.